# Spring Batch + Spring Boot - shutdown process

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm new to Spring Batch and I can't figure out how to terminate the Spring Boot process after job is finished.

In my **BatchConfiguration** class i configure jobs and steps:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BatchConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

   @Autowired
   private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

   @Autowired
   private MyExecutionListener listener;

   @Autowired
   private MyTasklet step1Task;

   @Bean
   public Job initJob() throws Exception {
        JobBuilder jobBuilder = jobBuilderFactory.get("my-job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener);

        FlowBuilder<FlowJobBuilder> builder = jobBuilder.flow(step1()).next(step2()).next(step3());

        return builder.build().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
       return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").tasklet(step1Task).build();
    }

    // and so on
```

After running the spring boot app, and every step is finished, I still have the process running. How can I stop it after job execution is finished?

Comment: What starters are you including?  If you have no web components in your app, it should shut down automatically once all jobs in the context have completed.

Comment: @MichaelMinella `spring-boot-starter-batch`, `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` and `spring-boot-starter-test`...is it due to _MongoDB starter_ ?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I found t! It was due to `spring-boot-starter-remote-shell`, that I don't know why and how it was in my pom.xml. Maybe Maven or STS automatically included it in my project..really don't know! Anyway, removing that dependency the process shuts down correctly. Thank you for driving me to the solution.

Comment: Any @Scheduler?